# Install4j Language and Message Issue

Tags: install4j

I have defined principle language in all my projects and also there is no other language added but it is observed that sometimes it shows language selection for uninstaller only and the frequency is also low not seen for installer and only language in language selection is

And also for some minimal machines i.e without GUI packages if we run the installer script it shows random messages to the user the frequency is quite low.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The language selection window can only be shown if additional languages are defined in the project. Maybe you have added them at some point and are using a build where they were configured.

The second message is displayed if no GUI can be shown. It is not a random message.

Comment: In general settings options i have added English as primary language in every project any other configurations to check means how to find out?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. "General Settings->Languages" is the only place to add additional languages.

Comment: So if additional language is not configured in General Settings->Languages then it should not give language selection popup right?

Comment: Yes, it will not do that, it needs at least one additional language in its config file.